# Beaglebone Black – unload cape

Tags: beagleboneblack, gpio, beagleboard

I am using a Beaglebone Black with the most recent OS (Debian Jessie, kernel v4.1). I need to be able to use pin P9_19 as a GPIO pin, but pin 19 has already been assigned to I2C_2_SCL.

When I try to use it, I get the error (octalbonescript):

> The pin P9_19 is not availble to write. Please make sure it is not used by another cape.

How can I unload the I2C cape to expose pin P9_19 for GPIO access?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

Using device tree overlay: echo **cape-universaln dtbo** file to **slots** 
or use [this](http://kilobaser.com/blog/2014-07-28-beaglebone-black-devicetreeoverlay-generator#dtogenerator) link to gernerate overlay file for gpio purpose, compile source dts file using

```
dtc -O dtb -o /lib/firmware/bspm_P9_19_17-00A0.dtbo -b 0 -@ /lib/firmware/bspm_P9_19_17-00A0.dts
```

and then deploy output dtbo file to **/lib/firmware** and then echo it to **slots**.

Also I personally recommend you to use this amazing library [Wirigbone](https://github.com/AbhraneelBera/wiringBone) for beaglebone, this is by far best for beaglbone.